# Sampling distribution of random sample

Tags: statistics

I am currently working on the following question: Suppose you have a finite population $P$ of size $N$. We select a sample $S_1$ using a random sampling without replacement of size $n_1$. Then we select a sample $S_2$ from $P-S_1$ using random sampling without replacement of size $n_2$.

Then we define $S= S_1 \cup S_2$. What is the sampling distribution of $S$?

$My \ answer$: 
There are $\binom{N}{n_1}$ possible ways to have a random sample $S_1$. Then there are $\binom{N-n_1}{n_2}$ possible ways to have a random sample $S_2$. Hence the number of possibilities for a random sample $S$ equals $\binom{N}{n_1}\binom{N-n_1}{n_2}$. Now we have counted possible outcomes multiple times. There are $\binom{n_1+n_2}{n_1}$ possible ways to have a specific selection. Hence the total numer of outcomes equals $\binom{N}{n_1}\binom{N-n_1}{n_2}/\binom{n_1+n_2}{n_1} = \binom{N}{n_1+n_2}$.

Therefore the probability of a specific sample equals $[\binom{N}{n_1+n_2}]^{-1}$

Is my reasoning correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do y0u mean by sampling distribution ?

Comment: If you take $N=3, n_1=n_2=1$ then $\binom{N}{n_1+n_2} = \binom{3}{2} = 3$. However $\binom{N}{n_1}\binom{N-n_1}{n_2} = \binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1} =6$.

Comment: @kees1 You are correct. I will delete my former comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but more directly you could say that this probability equals:$$\binom{N}{n_1+n_2}^{-1}$$

There is no essential difference between taking two consecutive samples of sizes $n_1$, $n_2$ respectively that are afterwards joined and one sample of size $n_1+n_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I noticed that I did not take into account that we can obtain the same random sample. In my previous answer I counted several samples more then once. I have changed my reasoning.